# What does this mean „Wärme, wo wir in Liebe Abschied nehmen"?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english

„Wärme, wo wir in Liebe Abschied nehmen"

I found this sentence on a [card at this website](http://www.gedichte-zitate.com/sprueche/abschied.html).
Besides the sentence in question, there is only a gras with spikelets shown.
The website is headed with:

"Abschied Sprüche
Kurze und nachdenkliche Worte, Abschiedssprüche und Gedichte für Trauer oder Trost auszusprechen. Schöne Zitate und Aporismen."

Comment: On it's own, the sentence is a bit odd. Is that from a poem or song text? Could you please edit your post and add more context? Furthermore, the community likes to see your own translation-efforts - that makes it easier to help you :)

Comment: @Marzipanherz thank you for answer. I saw the text in a picture. The author didn't write anything else about it so I'm really confused. I'm learning German and this sentence doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Can you describe and link the picture? Was that picture somehow related to grieving/funerals?

Comment: A recommendable machine translator is deepl.com. [Their English translation](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/W%C3%A4rme%2C%20wo%20wir%20in%20Liebe%20Abschied%20nehmen) makes as much sense as the German one - just in case you want to confirm your own translation attempts :)

Comment: Could be anything from "kiss your girlfriend good-bye in front of a campfire" to "fare-well to a relative in the crematory". Context, please!

Comment: @Marzipanherz http://www.gedichte-zitate.com/sprueche/abschied.html

Comment: I think "Abschied nehmen" means someone is dying, and warmth stands for comfort. So either someone is comforting someone dying, or vice versa.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis "Abschied nehmen" is often used in context of death, but not exclusively

Comment: Actually, I can not understand, why this question was closed. It _did not_ ask for translation but for the meaning. And using a dictionary doesn't really help to clarify the meaning of that phrase...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context:

> Wärme, wo wir in Liebe Abschied nehmen

is an aphorism by Monika Minder which can be found on [her website](http://www.minder-gedichte.ch/gedichte/2017/sprueche-aphorismen.html).

There you can find other aphorism like:

> Ursprung ist ständig.

or

> Jede Liebesgeschichte erzählt von Ostern.

---

As you can see there is no further context to this sentence and the author calls it an aphorism herself. Wikipedia says an [aphorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphorism) is

> a concise, terse, laconic, and/or memorable expression
>   of a general truth or principle.

The sentence sounds very odd. One may say it does not even make any sense.

You may translate it as

> Warmth, where we say farewell in love (sorry for any grammar mistakes in advance ;) )

So what does it mean?

I can think of two explanations.

1) "In Liebe Abschied nehmen" may refer to a hug between lovers when they take farewell. They are near each other and provide warmth. Also their love provide warmth right as this moment they are together.

2) "Wärme" may be a kind of request like "Wärme (den Ort)". So it says

> Warm up (the place), where we take farewell in love

like a bed or whatever.

But whatever Monika Minder wanted to say ... i think its "meh".

Comment: Dunno, but ISTM that someone is dying and that there is a person comforting him or her (comfort = warmth), or vice versa (i.e. the dying is comforting the person or persons left behind alive).

Answer (score 2):

This phrase itself is nothing you would say or write in standard German (and it is not even a complete grammatical sentence, just in case you were wondering).

To get an idea, think of arty social media pictures with a supposedly *deep message*, this one might be hash-tagged *#grieving #sadness #farewell* or similar.

However, it is a matter of taste, whether one would really like to get such a message when *really* grieving.

Comment: ah, didn't see the possible grieving interpretation. I like the "supposedly deep message" part :D

Comment: @mtwd :D I couldn't resist

Comment: It sounds sad, but I know people who collect such messages (on their cellphones) and then send them to others. <sigh>